# Proving that $2x \equiv 48 \mod 100$ has only $2$ valid solutions $24$ and $74$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How would I go about proving that $2x \equiv 48\mod 100$ solutions are $ x \in  \{ 24+100Z\} \cup \{74+100Z\}$

I can see its trivial to prove that those two are solutions, but how do I show that they are the only ones?

Comment: Hint:  $100\,|\,2(x-24)\iff 50\,|\,(x-24)$

Comment: Well, strictly speaking there is 124 and 174 and 224 and 274 and ...

Comment: 2x = 48 mod 100 mean 2x = 48 + 100k so x = 24 + 50 k so x = 24 mod 50 so x = 24 +k50 \mod 100

Comment: Thanks Henning, I fixed the question to be what I meant to ask in the first place.

Comment: I wouldn't have fixed that.  You should get used to thinking in terms of modulo and residue classes.  "24 and 74 are the only two solutions modulo 100" or "24 and 74 are the only two solutions in the reduced residue class mod 100" *are* correct ways of putting it.  Yes 124, 174 are other solutions but they are *equivalet* solutions modulo 100. And as residues "24" and "74" are not the *integers* 24 but representatives of the entire sets {24 +k100} and {76+k100}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma:

$a \equiv b \mod c \iff ak \equiv bk \mod ck; k \ne 0$

Proof $a \equiv b \mod c \iff c|(a-b) \iff c*k|k(a-b) \iff ck|ak - bk \iff ak \equiv bk \mod ck$

....

So $2x \equiv 48 \mod 100 \implies x \equiv 24 \mod 50 \implies x = 24 + k50$

The only $24 + 50k$ in the residue class modulo $100$ are $24$ and $74$.

....

If you are uncomfortable stating point blank that obviously $24$ and $74$ are the only $24 + k50$ in the reduced residue class consider this:

$k$ is either even or odd.  If $k$ is even then $k = 2k'$ for some $k'$ and $24 + 50k = 24 + 50*2k' = 24 + 100k \equiv 24 \mod 100$.

If $k$ is odd then $k =2k' + 1$ for some $k'$.  So $24 + 50k = 24 + 50(2k' + 1) = 74 + 100k' \equiv 74 \mod 100$.  Those are the only two options.

In general:

Lemma:  If $a \equiv b \mod m$ and $m|n$ (say $n = dm$) then $a \equiv b + km \mod n$ for some $k = 0... (d-1)$

Proof:  $a \equiv b$ means $a = b + jm$ for some $j$.  $k$ may be written as $j = qd +k; 0 \le r \le d$.  So $a = b + (qd+k)m = b+ km + qmd = b +km + qn \equiv b+km \mod n$.

Comment: Yeah I could see this too, just wasn't sure it was enough to say that they are  the only ones in the residue class without proving that as well, which is I guess where I was getting caught up.  Thanks for the clear answer... since I am a newbie I can't upvote, but +1 to you kind sir.

Comment: You might want to talk with your professor about just what you can and can't claim point blank.

Comment: Thanks again for the extended answer and the feedback, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$2x\equiv 48=2\cdot 24\mod 100=2\cdot50\iff x\equiv 24\mod 50.$$